# What's the purpose of having default enum value as 'unspecified' in Google protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I can see that in Google Chrome (Chromium) sources first enum value (default) is declared as "unspecified":

```
// The type of a subresource filtering rule.
enum RuleType {
  RULE_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0;

  RULE_TYPE_COMMENT = 1;  // Comment rule.
  RULE_TYPE_URL = 2;      // Network level filtering rule based on URL pattern.
  RULE_TYPE_CSS = 3;      // Element hiding rule based on a CSS selector.
};

...

// Types of anchors that can be used to constrain where a URL pattern must
// begin/end in the URL in order to be considered a match.
enum AnchorType {
  ANCHOR_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0;

  // Acts like a '*' wildcard at the respective end of a pattern.
  ANCHOR_TYPE_NONE = 1;
  // The pattern must match from the start/until the end of the URL.
  ANCHOR_TYPE_BOUNDARY = 2;
  // The pattern must match starting with the TLD+n of the URL's domain, but the
  // scheme and subdomains (if any) can be arbitrary.
  ANCHOR_TYPE_SUBDOMAIN = 3;
};
...
```

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/url_pattern_index/proto/rules.proto

What's the purpose of doing that?

Take into account it's [`protobuf` 2](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/url_pattern_index/proto/rules.proto?l=5) so the fields can be marked with `optional` and `required` and `unspecified` enum value can be removed by just making the field optional.

Let's say:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/url_pattern_index/proto/rules.proto?l=22:

```
// The format of a URL pattern.
enum UrlPatternType {
  URL_PATTERN_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0;

  // A pattern without special characters, e.g. "example.com".
  URL_PATTERN_TYPE_SUBSTRING = 1;

  // The pattern contains one or more wildcards, namely '*' and/or '^'
  // characters. The '*' matches any sequence of characters, while the '^'
  // matches a separator, i.e. anything but a letter, a digit, or one of [-._%].
  URL_PATTERN_TYPE_WILDCARDED = 2;

  // The pattern is a regular expression.
  URL_PATTERN_TYPE_REGEXP = 3;
};
```

but the field is `optional`: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/url_pattern_index/proto/rules.proto?l=150:

```
 optional UrlPatternType url_pattern_type = 6;
```

Why just don't pass it instead of passing `unspecified` value?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most important reason is to provide a clean path if you ever want to move to proto3 in the future, since this is the only option that will be directly compatible.

However, it also simplifies usage on a number of platforms, since enums vary wildly between different languages. It also makes the default value very obviously noticeable as "probably wrong" - again: how a default new instance gets initialized can vary wildly between platforms / languages, and the level of control you hope for might not be available on some platforms.

Comment: I tend to agree what relates to migration to protobuf 3 (using protobuf 2 in 2017 when protobuf 3 already exists looks really strange).  What about clear way of making know the value is most likely wrong reminds me *magic value* anti-pattern instead of just not having any value at all.

Comment: @4ntoine and that's great, but it might not be *possible* (at least, not reasonably) to have "no value" on some languages/platforms/frameworks. The entire point of x-plat is that it needs to be usable on most of them.

Comment: makes sense. btw i've emailed google developer that wrote that code. probably he can explain

Comment: What was the answer from the developer?

Comment: @4ntoine I guess they're asking you ^^^